# How did imprisoned Sultan fulfill his bodily functions?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

In *Once Upon a Time in Wonderland*, the genie and the imprisoned Sultan were imprisoned in suspended cages. The question is how do they poop?

Obviously, a genie wouldn't need to. But what about the Sultan? And for a while, Alice's father.

Possibilities

- His wizard son had taken the need away. But why then was his need to eat not taken away? Just to torture him with bad food?
- The wizard placed an invisible toilet bowl.
- He had to position and aim perfectly, through the small squares so as not to stain the bottom of the cage.

Otherwise, what then?

[image: The Sultan in his suspended "bird cage": metal bars bell shaped with a cross patch floor]

Answer (score 5):

As much as I hate to lead with an "out of universe" answer, the simple fact is that it's an example of a TV Trope called "[Nobody Poops](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops)"

The reality is, of course that soiling yourself in a gibbet cage was one of the various indignities that you'd suffer before your inevitable death from starvation, thirst or disease.

[image: A gibbet cage hangs from the outside wall of a castle next to a large open doorway]

Comment: Have you watched the show? The cage in the show had a base that is dissimilar to the one in the picture you provide. The one in the show would result in soil mounds accumulating. And I don't see mounds or stains. He could be careful once but not all the time, especially in his state. Please watch the show.

Comment: A screenshot might help but the simple answer is going to be either "someone cleans it up" or "It's just a TV show, relax"